# how to save data from redis to a file in disk and read back to redis?

Tags: c#, redis

i can write to redis and read from it in a program

however, after close server, i guess data are deleted from memory

how to make the data in redis saved to disk and next time i open redis so that

it can open the data, let console program to read it?

if my computer restart itself due to power off suddenly, can redis recover the status and

let program can read previous data?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost");
            redisClient.FlushAll();

            var redisTodos = redisClient.As<Todo>();;
            Todo todo1 = new Todo();
            todo1.Content = "wind";
            todo1.Id = redisTodos.GetNextSequence();
            todo1.Order = 1;
            todo1.Done = false;

            redisTodos.Store(todo1);
            var savedTodo = redisTodos.GetById(todo1.Id);
            var allTodos = redisTodos.GetAll();
            foreach(var i in allTodos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.Content);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Redis Persistance](http://redis.io/topics/persistence).

You might want to checkout commands like [SAVE](http://redis.io/commands/save) or [BGSAVE](http://redis.io/commands/bgsave) which dump data to disk as rdb files. These files can later be used to load data into redis on startup

Comment: How to restore it from the saved file?

Answer (score 0):

problem here is that the first thing your program do is flushing the complete db

```
redisClient.FlushAll();
```

the place where redis save and load his dump file is in the .conf file given to redis when you start the server

```
$ redis-server /home/user/redis.conf
```

if you start the server without any .conf, redis will save and load the dump file from the folder where you launch the redis-server

```
$ cd /home/user/myfolder
$ redis-server
```

here dumb.rdb file will be writed to /home/user/myfolder/dump.rdb

for saving the db, just copy the dump.rdb file

you could also have a look at [rdd](https://github.com/r043v/rdd) who's a pretty flexible tool