# Write a generic C# class which backup and restore a Redis key (an individual key (or key pattern)) of any data type to and from file?

Tags: c#, redis

The following code can backup and restore Redis key of data type string. How to create a generic function to backup/restore any data types besides Strings (Lists, Sets, Hashes, Sorted sets, Streams, Geospatial indexes, Bitmaps, Bitfields, ....)

```
using System;
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System.IO;

class RedisKeyBackupRestore
{
    private readonly ConnectionMultiplexer _redis;
    private readonly IDatabase _db;
    private readonly string _backupFile;

    public RedisKeyBackupRestore(string connectionString, int db, string backupFile)
    {
        _redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
        _db = _redis.GetDatabase(db);
        _backupFile = backupFile;
    }

    public void BackupKey(string key) // key can be any type
    {
        var value = _db.StringGet(key); // It needs _db.SetMembers(key) for set type
        using (var file = new StreamWriter(_backupFile))
        {
            file.WriteLine($"{key},{value}");
        }
    }

    public void RestoreKey(string key)
    {
        using (var file = new StreamReader(_backupFile))
        {
            var line = file.ReadLine();
            var parts = line.Split(',');
            var restoredKey = parts[0];
            var restoredValue = parts[1];
            _db.StringSet(restoredKey, restoredValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743129/how-to-save-data-from-redis-to-a-file-in-disk-and-read-back-to-redis

Comment: The answer suggest up use BGSAVE. How to restore from a saved file?

Comment: Btw, it seems the SAVE command save the whole the whole data set instead of individual key or key pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your code generic:

1. Call the `dump` command, i.e. `dump key`, to backup value of a given key. It works on any types, e.g. string, set, hash. The `dump` command returns the serialized value in binary string format.
2. Write the key and value to file with a binary safe way.
3. When restoring the key-value pair, you can run the `restore` command, i.e. `restore key value`.

Comment: I actually need to save the file to AWS S3. Is it possible to read the dumped file and save it to S3? The dump command doesn't specify the file name?

Comment: Of course you can save it to S3. `dump` command returns the serialized value of the key, and you need to write the key-value to S3 manually. For example, use the key with some prefix as filename.